# Variable inside double quotes doesn't work as argument

Tags: bash

I'm trying to pass arguments in a variable to `curl` and it fails.  I turned on `set -x` to get more information, and I'm really confused about all the single quotes I'm seeing here.

```
curlopts="-ksS -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'"

$ curl "$curlopts" https://localhost
+ curl '-ksS -H '\''Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'\''' https://localhost
curl: option -ksS -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded': is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

It works without quotes like `curl $curlopts https://localhost` but I thought it's generally bad practice to use a variable without quotes.

Comment: As you see in the -x output, quoting means the entire variable is passed as one argument. However, curl expects each to be separate.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
curlopts="-ksS -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'"
```

sets `curlopts` to `-ksS -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`.

After the above, this:

```
curl "$curlopts" https://localhost
```

is equivalent to this:

```
curl "-ksS -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'" https://localhost
```

meaning that it calls `curl` with two arguments: `-ksS -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`, and `https://localhost`.

But of course, you want to call `curl` with four arguments: `-ksS`, `-H`, `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and `https://localhost`.

To achieve that, I recommend using an array:

```
curlopts=(-ksS -H Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

curl "${curlopts[@]}" https://localhost
```

where the `"${arrayname[@]}"` syntax expands, magically, into a *separate* double-quoted word for each element of the array.

(Note: I've removed the single-quotes because they aren't needed here — none of the characters in `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` require quoting — but if they make you feel happier, you can safely re-add them.)